# When you upgrade an engine that has new migrations, how to run them?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refinerycms

I just updated `refinerycms-news` engine in my Gemfile from `'~> 0.9.8'` to `:git => 'https://github.com/resolve/refinerycms-news.git'`, and now there is an error caused by a missing column. The migration to create the column can be found in the installed gem, but `rake db:migrate` does nothing. Is there another rake task or other step that will run it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to follow this convention for Refinery CMS:

```
rails generate refinerycms_news
rake db:migrate
```

The generator copies only new migrations in and then rake db:migrate runs them.

Cheers,
Phil

Comment: In versions 2.0.0 and above it's changed to:   

    rails generate refinery:news &&
    rake db:migrate